# Instagram min_tag_id leaves out posts

Tags: pagination, instagram, instagram-api

I am using the Instagram real-time API to get the most recent posts of a certain hashtag. Therefore I *subscribed* to the API and Instagram makes a *callback* everytime a post gets tagged with that hashtag.

Ever 5 seconds my application checks if there where any callbacks (I register every callback to make sure, that I don't make any requests to Instagram if there where no callbacks before)

When there was at least one callback, I make a request to the "tags/media/recent" endpoint. Additionaly I store the `min_tag_id` of every response and send it with the next request. That way Instagram only sends me the "newest" content.

**So far so good.**

Instagram is "kind" enough to indicate the `min_tag_id` I should use next. In a normal response it should look like this (I shortened the response a little):

```
 "pagination":{
    "min_tag_id": "1061443126713008625"    // the min_tag_id I can use for the next request
 },
 "data":[
     {
         "id" : "1061443126713008625_782775143", // id of the first post
         // rest of the data...
     },{
         "id" : "1061443123569823070_176952626", // id of another post
         // rest of the data...
     }
 ]
```

As you can see, the `min_tag_id` given by Instagram is part of the `id` of the *first post*.

"min_tag_id":"**1061443126713008625**"
"id":**1061443126713008625**_782775143"

So next time I make a request with *that* `min_tag_id`, I receive all posts coming afterwards.

**But**

Sometimes Instagram gives me a `min_tag_id` but doesn't send me the post with that id. Like so:

```
 "pagination": {
    "min_tag_id": "1061443926677909216"
 }
 "data":[
     {
         "id" : "1061443924303843601_1666507083"
          // ...
     },{
         "id" : "1061443905925893282_479418538"
         // ...
     }
 ]
```

And the next time I use the new `min_tag_id` I get all the posts coming afterwards but not the post with *that* id. 
**In short** I am missing some posts when using the pagination.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Is the pagination not meant for that? 
Sometimes Instagram doesn't send me anything at all (besides the pagination) and sometimes the post with the `min_tag_id` is contained in  a response afterwards. 
If I am not doing anything wrong and if I just have to live with it, does anyone know a way to get the real `id` of the post with just the `min_tag_id` ? As you can see they are not the same and I don't know the last part (`***_1666507083`)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29870679/325521).

Have you tried passing in a large `count` parameter as suggested by [@Amir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4267030/amir-rahimi-farahani)

> You will also need to pass a large `count` parameter and follow the
>   pagination of the response to receive all data without losing anything
>   when the speed of tagging is faster than your polling.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29877510/325521

Comment: Thank you for your response and sorry it took me so long to check this out. Apparently I'm not alone with this problem and your links where very interesting. Although in my case I only a few  posts (1-5) and the post with the `min_tag_id` is still missing. So it should have nothing to do with "too many posts" as Instagram will send approx. 35-40 posts per request. However I tried using the "count" parameter and simply counted the number of callbacks from Instagram. So when counting 10 callbacks, I ask for 10 posts. But this is too bad regarding performance and there where still posts missing